# Safari setting to inform preferred language for Google search?

Tags: safari, search, google

The goal is to configure my IOS ecosystem (iPad, iPhone, MacBook) to return Google searches in English.  Is there a Safari setting to realize said goal?

Answer (score 2):

There's a Google setting, if you're signed in.

The browser in itself does not dictate the language, your geolocation is going to overrule that a lot of the time.

Comment: I was just going to leave a similar post but in comments.  This link might add some context: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/13511324